# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint . Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a primary key constraint created like so:

```
    CONSTRAINT [APP_NOTIFICATION_LOG_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   
    [ID] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I had some records in the table that I have now deleted.

I manually find the next ID to insert like so:

```
SELECT @maxid_log = max(ID) + 1 FROM APP_NOTIFICATION_LOG;
```

And then I try to insert the record:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[APP_NOTIFICATION_LOG]([ID],[COLOR],[ACTIVE],[FK_SYS_USERS_ID],[FK_APP_NOTIFICATIONS_ID], [MESSAGE],[WIN_USER_CREATOR], [FK_JOBR_RESOURCE_ID])
SELECT -- log notification created
    @maxid_log,
    anc.COLOR,
    1,
    anc.[FK_SYS_USERS_ID],
    an.id,
    'Notification cancelled!',
    @creatorUserId,
    @jobrResourceDbId
FROM [dbo].[APP_NOTIFICATIONS] an
    INNER JOIN  [dbo].[APP_NOTIFICATION_CONFIG] anc on anc.id = @configId   
WHERE an.[FK_JOBR_RESOURCE_ID] = @jobrResourceDbId
```

At this stage get the error in the title. It also says that the value 5 is a dublicate. But running a select:

```
SELECT * FROM APP_NOTIFICATION_LOG WHERE ID = 5
```

...returns zero records.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Use an IDENTITY column, using `select max()+1` is not safe if multiple sessions run the SQL at the same time (or there are multiple rows in the insert).

Comment: Noted. I will update my script accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Select is returning more than one record ?

Run it by itself and see how many rows are returned.

Comment: That was in fact the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner join returns more than just 1 result, so you try to insert several rows with same id.